# OpenCV floodfill with mask

Tags: opencv, flood-fill

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill) for OpenCV's floodfill function states:

> The function uses and updates the mask, so you take responsibility of
>   initializing the mask content. Flood-filling cannot go across non-zero
>   pixels in the mask. For example, an edge detector output can be used
>   as a mask to stop filling at edges. It is possible to use the same
>   mask in multiple calls to the function to make sure the filled area
>   does not overlap.

How does the function update the mask?  Does it set all the pixels within the floodfill to some non-zero value?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All zero-valued pixels in the same connected component as the seed point of the mask are replaced by the value you specify. This value must be added to the `flags` parameter, left-shifted by 8 bits:

```
uchar fillValue = 128;
cv::floodFill(img, mask, seed, cv::Scalar(255) ,0, cv::Scalar(), cv::Scalar(), 4 | cv::FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY | (fillValue << 8));
```

A simple, but perhaps enlightening example follows. Creating an image like so:

```
//Create simple input image
cv::Point seed(4,4);
cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(100,100,CV_8UC1);
cv::circle(img, seed, 20, cv::Scalar(128),3);
```

Results in this image:

[image: Original image]

Then, creating a mask and flood-filling it:

```
//Create a mask from edges in the original image
cv::Mat mask;
cv::Canny(img, mask, 100, 200);
cv::copyMakeBorder(mask, mask, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);

//Fill mask with value 128
uchar fillValue = 128;
cv::floodFill(img, mask, seed, cv::Scalar(255) ,0, cv::Scalar(), cv::Scalar(), 4 | cv::FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY | (fillValue << 8));
```

Gives this result:

[image: Flood-filled mask]

The white pixels in the mask are the result of edge detection, while the grey pixels are the result of the flood-fill.

**UPDATE:**
In response to the comment, flag value `4` specifies the pixel neighborhood with which to compare the color value difference. From the documentation:

> Lower bits contain a connectivity value, 4 (default) or 8, used within the function. Connectivity determines which neighbors of a pixel are considered.

When the `cv::FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY` flag is not passed, **both** the image and the mask are updated, but the flood filling will stop at at any nonzero mask values.

Comment: Would someone rewrite this peace of code in the answer to java, please?

Comment: @Aurelius Thanks for pointing out that the pixels of the mask have to be zero-valued in order to get filled. This hint saved my day....

Comment: Hint for python users: This works exactly the same way, here's the syntax: `flood_value = 128
cv.floodFill(img, mask, seed, 255, 5, 5, flags=cv.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY | (flood_value << 8))`

Answer (score 13):

And a python version

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
im = cv2.imread("seagull.jpg")
h,w,chn = im.shape
seed = (w/2,h/2) # needs to be a tuple of int  can use (w//2,h//2) too

mask = np.zeros((h+2,w+2),np.uint8)

floodflags = 4
floodflags |= cv2.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY
floodflags |= (255 << 8)

num,im,mask,rect = cv2.floodFill(im, mask, seed, (255,0,0), (10,)*3, (10,)*3, floodflags)

cv2.imwrite("seagull_flood.png", mask)
```

(Seagull image from Wikimedia: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Quality_images#/media/File:Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg)

Result: [image: result]

Comment: One particularly important thing to notice is that when specifying a point `x` and `y` axis are switched compared to numpy indexing.

Comment: With the same image and code, I get only the edges - https://drive.google.com/open?id=17DhliW4OIy2iNPJkXglbNPdgaEgpGACf Can you please advise why this might be the case?

Comment: @aneeshaasc try (7,)*3, (7,)*3 instead of (10,)*3, (10,)*3 in                   
   cv2.floodFill(im, mask, seed, (255,0,0), (10,)*3, (10,)*3, floodflags)

Comment: What's the meaning of the flag 255<<8 ? I refer inparticular to the <<8 part as I kknow that 255 means that the mask will be filled with taht value in the region indentified

Comment: @Aelius see the docs for a full description: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga366aae45a6c1289b341d140839f18717

Comment: @Aelius https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift

Answer (score 0):

Per Aurelius' answer, the mask needs to be zeroed.

Checking comment in the source, it stated that

> Since this is both an input and output parameter, you must take responsibility
>   of initializing it. Flood-filling cannot go across non-zero pixels in the input mask.

The mask will impact the result so need to be zeroed before use:

```
cv::Mat mask;
mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows + 2, img.cols + 2, CV_8UC1);
```