# OpenCV FloodFill with multiple seeds

Tags: python, c++, opencv, flood-fill, simplecv

Is there a floodFill function for python/openCV that takes a list of seeds and starts changing the color of its neighbours? I know that simplecv as a function like that [SimpleCV floodFill](http://simplecv.org/docs/SimpleCV.html#i/SimpleCV.ImageClass.Image/floodFill). OpenCV says it has two floodFill functions when that uses a mask and another one that doesn't, [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill), I'm not being able to use the opencv floodfill function without a mask and with a list of seeds. Any help?

This is what I'm trying to do so far:

```
A=array([[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]],np.uint8)
mask = np.ones((A.shape[0]+2,A.shape[0]+2),np.uint8)
mask[1:-1,1:-1] = np.zeros((A.shape))
cv.floodFill(A, mask, (3,0), 0,0,0,  flags=4|cv.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY)
print mask
```

returned mask:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Expected mask:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Original Image:

```
[[0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely at the documentation, that's one of the purpose of mask. You can call multiple times the function (2nd version) every time with a different seed, and at the end mask will contain the area that has been floodfilled. If a new seed belongs to an area already floodfilled, your function call will return immediately.

Use the FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY flag, and then use this mask to paint your input image with the desidered filling color at the end with a [setTo()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=setto#Mat&%20Mat::setTo%28InputArray%20value,%20InputArray%20mask%29) (You'll have to use a subimage of Mask! Removing first and last row and column). Note that your floodfill might produce different results depending on the order you process your seed points if you set `loDiff` or `upDiff` to something different than the default value zero.

Take also a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16719206/2436175).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to do as you said but I wasn't able to succeed. I updated my question with more details.

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes Yep, you got swapped x and y in your seed point, (3,0) is last pixel of first raw, not last pixel of first column. Coordinates are (x,y), namely (col,raw)

Comment: now I feel dumb.. ahah thank you very much! I still need to get use to this x,y coordinates.