# How to differentiate two adjacent connected shape

Tags: python, opencv

[image]

I want to differentiate two component as shown in this picture.
The marked section is my original crop and all other area is weed and I want to detect my only crop section. How to do that in python?

Comment: How are you detecting the components? Can you share your code and your results? What criteria do you use to distinguish the component you're looking for?

Comment: I am going to detect weed(unnecessary crop in field) from the field. so what to do if both are merged and differentiate them.

Comment: The components do not appear to be merged in your example image, so it's difficult to determine what type of help you need. Have you tried applying `connectedComponents` to this image?

Comment: Using connectedComponents and contours I got my desired result....Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to identify closed loop object in your shape, not sure but it may helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with `findContours` and `drawContours` functions, they are described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html).

Also it would be possible to find all closed shapes with `floodFill` ([with mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705721/opencv-floodfill-with-mask)).